# CSS - tooltip only with css and html doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do **simple tooltip** only with **css3** and html, but the **transition doesn't work**. What am I doing wrong?

### HTML

```
<p>
    This has tooltip
</p>
<div class="tooltip">Tooltip content</div>
```

### CSS

```
p {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: aqua;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

div.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
    top: 0px;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0.0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
}

p:hover + div.tooltip {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1.0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MCDg4/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Update / Alternate solution***

For a modern browser CSS3 solution you could use pseudo elements..

```
<span data-tooltip="I am the tooltip">This has a tooltip</span>
```

and

```
[data-tooltip]{
    position:relative;
}
[data-tooltip]:before{
    content:attr(data-tooltip);
    position:absolute;
    bottom:110%;
    padding:10px;
    background:#666;
    opacity:0;
    color:white;
    font-size:smaller;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 1s ease;
    -o-transition:opacity 1s ease;
    transition:opacity 1s ease;
    pointer-events:none;
}
[data-tooltip]:hover:before{
    opacity:1;
}
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/BJ2tr/

(*this could be done without pseudo-elements by nesting the tooltip inside the elements that it refers to, and adjusting the css accordingly*)

---

Unfortunately when you change `display` from `none` to something else, you cannot have transitions.

Instead of `display:none` you could just offset it outside of the window (*with `top:-9999px`*) and bring it to position when showing it.

```
div.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
    top: -999px; /*CHANGED THIS AND REMOVED display:none*/
    display: none;
    opacity: 0.0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
}

p:hover + div.tooltip {
    opacity: 1.0;
    top: 0px; /*ADDED THIS AND REMOVED display:block*/
    transition: opacity 1s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

This will, however, not fade out (*only in*) since it moves it away on mouseout (*so it actually does fade but you do not see it because it is outside the viewport*)..

Comment: For general use, this answer seems better to me.  For instance, leaving the element in place and just setting opacity 0 still prevents me from selecting any text underneath it (when I tested in jsFiddle.)  However, jsFiddle seems to also ignore `top:-999px`, not sure what that's about.

Comment: On the other hand, `left:-999px` works in jsFiddle just fine.

Comment: Just noticed the comment on the missing fadeout... maybe it's not better.  I guess neither solution is perfect.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli: that looks fine. Why now is possible select the text?

Comment: it works because of the `pointer-events:none;` which instruct the mouse to ignore the tooltip.

Answer (score 5):

### Explanation

You put `transition` only on `opacity`, while when changing to `display:block;` it is shown as a block with `opacity:1;` by default.

### [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/MCDg4/1/)

*(JSFiddle)*

Delete the `display:none;` and `display:block` on your tooltip element.

Comment: This works for the OP's example.  However see my comment on the other answer. The presence of the invisible element seems to matter when there's content underneath it.

Comment: Then adding a negative `z-index` and reducing the `height` and `width` to *zero* could fix this. Or maybe a `text-indent: -450px;` could do it too